# Why is the command handler in discord.js not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So, I was developing a Discord Bot and wanted to use the Command Handler but there is something wrong with the for cycle.

Index.js code:

```
client.commands = new Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command)
}
```

And this is the command code:

```
module.export = {
    data: {
        name: "ban",
        description: "Ban an user"
    },
    async execute(interaction){
        //Code
    }
}
```

The error tells me:

```
client.commands.set(command.data.name, command)
                                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/yihanzhou/Desktop/LavaBot/index.js:13:38)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1112:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1166:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:834:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

what's wrong with this code?

Comment: It might you miss spelled the `export` to `exports` or you have another file on your `command` folder without any `data.name`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's because of an error:

you typed
`module.export = {`

instead of
`module.exports = {`

here it is !